# Asterisk Realtime Extensions - ODBC Setup

Tags: sql-server, odbc, asterisk

I'm trying to configure Asterisk to read the dialplan for a specific context from my MS-SQL database.

I've followed every step here:

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+RealTime+Extensions

Where though do I enter details of the SQL server, i.e. i've specified I want to use ODBC but where to setup that ODBC connection with servername/user/pass/port etc?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have setup microsoft driver

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh568451%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

After that change settings of /etc/odbc.ini and /etc/odbcinst.ini

http://www.asteriskdocs.org/en/3rd_Edition/asterisk-book-html-chunk/installing_configuring_odbc.html

Answer (score 0):

- Download and install latest version [`unixODBC`](http://www.unixodbc.org/doc/FreeTDS2.html)
- Download and install latest version  [`FreeTDS`](http://www.freetds.org/)
- Once you have installed this two pakages, you will need to do some
  configurations

  1-  in `/etc/odbcinst.ini` you need to point to the freetds driver

  2 - in `/etc/odbc.ini` that's where you put your datasource

[Example](http://www.asteriskdocs.org/en/3rd_Edition/asterisk-book-html-chunk/installing_configuring_odbc.html):

```
[SQLServer] 
Driver  = FreeTDS 
Description     = Some Descritpiton 
Trace           = No 
Server          = 192.168.1.25 
Port            = 1433 
Database        = dbNamehere
```